# RxJS: Observable stream piped to groupBy() followed by concatMap(); data for subsequent keys lost

Tags: rxjs6

I am trying to use the RxJS `groupBy` operator followed by `concatMap` to collect records into individual groups based on some keys.

I have noticed that when `concatMap` follows a `groupBy` operator, it seems to lose the data for all the keys that occur after the first one.

For Example:

Consider the following code block:

```
// DOES NOT WORK
const records = ['a:1', 'b:2', 'c:3', 'd:1', 'e:2', 'f:3', 'g:1'];
const clicks = new Subject();

const result = clicks.pipe(
  groupBy(x => x.substr(2,1)),
  concatMap(ev$ => ev$.pipe(map(x => ({key: ev$.key, value: x})))),
);
const subscription = result.subscribe(x => console.log(x));

records.forEach(x => clicks.next(x));

// Expected Output:
// { key: '1', value: 'a:1' }
// { key: '1', value: 'd:1' }
// { key: '1', value: 'g:1' }
// { key: '2', value: 'b:2' }
// { key: '2', value: 'e:2' }
// { key: '3', value: 'c:3' }
// { key: '3', value: 'f:3' }
// 
// Actual Output:
// { key: '1', value: 'a:1' }
// { key: '1', value: 'd:1' }
// { key: '1', value: 'g:1' }
// ...Nothing more -- no results for key 2 and 3
```

However, when I use the `concatMap` operator on its own, it behaves as expected.

```
// WORKS
const records = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'];
const clicks = new Subject();

const result = clicks.pipe(
  concatMap(ev => ev.subject$.pipe(take(4), map(x => ev.key + x))),
);
const subscription = result.subscribe(x => console.log(x));

records.forEach(x => clicks.next({key: x, subject$: interval(1000)}));

// Expected & Actual Output:
// a0
// a1
// a2
// a3
// b0
// b1
// b2
// b3
// c0
// c1
// c2
// c3
// d0
// d1
// d2
// d3
// e0
// e1
// e2
// e3
// f0
// f1
// f2
// f3
// g0
// g1
// g2
// g3
```

Reading through the documentation for RxJS [`groupBy`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/groupBy) and [`concatMap`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/concatMap) does not provide me with any clues as to what could be going on here. Whereas the section on RxJS `concatMap` at [reactivex.io](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/flatmap.html) leads me to believe that this should work.

Can anyone help me understand what's going on with the first scenario here? How can I get the first scenario to work?

Comment: The keys within your source are interleaved, so when using `groupBy`, you need to use `mergeMap` not `concatMap`.

Comment: @cartant As far as I understand `concatMap` internally calls `mergeMap` anyway. So, its pretty much the same. Moreover, I do need the `concatMap` functionality rather than the `mergeMap` functionality; as in, I want the group for the second key to start emitting only after all values from the first have been exhausted.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I finally seem to have figured out what the issue is here.

In Scenario #1 in the question above, the code pipes the source stream first into the `groupBy` operator, followed by the `concatMap` operator. And this combination of operators seem to be causing this problem.

#### Inner workings of `groupBy` and `mergeMap`

Reading through [the code for the `groupBy` operator](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/operators/groupBy.ts#L138), I realized that `groupBy` internally creates a new `Subject` instance for each key that is found in the source stream. All values belonging to that key are then immediately emitted by that `Subject` instance.

All the `Subject` instances are wrapped into `GroupedObservale`s and emitted downstream by the `groupBy` operator. This stream of `GroupedObservable` instances is the input to the `concatMap` operator.

The `concatMap` operator internally calls the `mergeMap` operator with a value of 1 for `concurrency`, which means only one source observable is subscribed to concurrently.

The `mergeMap` operator subscribes to only one observable, or as many observables as is allowed by the `conccurency` parameter, and holds all other observables in "buffer" till the first one has completed.

#### How does this create the problem?

Firstly, now that I have read through the code for these operators, I am not too sure if this is a "problem".

Nevertheless the behavior I described in the question occurs because while the `groupBy` operator emits individual values using the corresponding `Subject` instance immediately, the `mergeMap` operator would not have subscribed to that particular `Subject`. Hence, all values from the source stream that are being emitted using that `Subject` are lost.

I have tried to illustrate this problem in a rough marble diagram:
[image: groupBy to concatMap issue]

This is not a "problem" with the way these operators work, but perhaps with the way I understood these operators and possibly the documentation (particularly the documentation for `concatMap` which maybe a bit confusing for the folks new to RxJS).

This can be easily fixed by getting the `groupBy` operator to use a `ReplaySubject` instead of `Subject` to emit the grouped values. The `groupBy` accepts a `subjectSelector` parameter that allows us to switch the `Subject` instance with a `ReplaySubject` instance.

The following code works:

```
// THIS VERSION WORKS
const records = ['a:1', 'b:2', 'c:3', 'd:1', 'e:2', 'f:3', 'g:1'];
const clicks = new Subject();

const result = clicks.pipe(
  groupBy(x => x.substr(2,1), null, null, () => new ReplaySubject()),
  concatMap(ev$ => ev$.pipe(map(x => ({key: ev$.key, value: x})))),
);
const subscription = result.subscribe(x => console.log(x));

records.forEach(x => clicks.next(x));

// We also need to explicity complete() the source
// stream to ensure that the observable stream for
// the first GroupedObservable completes allowing
// the concatMap operator to move to the second
// GroupedObservable.
clicks.complete();

// Expected and Actual output
// { key: '1', value: 'a:1' }
// { key: '1', value: 'd:1' }
// { key: '1', value: 'g:1' }
// { key: '2', value: 'b:2' }
// { key: '2', value: 'e:2' }
// { key: '3', value: 'c:3' }
// { key: '3', value: 'f:3' }
```

#### Why does Scenario 2 work?

Scenario 2 in my question works fine because `interval` just creates an Observable but does not start emitting values. Hence, all values from that Observable are available when `mergeMap` finally subscribes to it.

Comment: excellent investigation! if you decide to write an article on this, I'll be happy to publish it in [angular-in-depth](https://blog.angularindepth.com)

Comment: Sure! I was meaning to put this up anyway. Let me put this together into a coherent write up and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: awesome! get in touch with me [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/maxim_koretskyi) or email me m.koretskyi@gmail.com

Comment: Kiran, we are still waiting for the article)

Comment: Here it is. https://blog.angularindepth.com/those-hidden-gotchas-within-rxjs-7d5c57406041

Comment: Awesome, Kiran! Thanks for the excellent article! Can you recommend any resources on RX design patterns?

Comment: Fantastic, it took me far too long to find this.  The call signature is now depreciated, new signature is `groupBy(x => x.substr(2,1), {connector:() => new ReplaySubject()})`

Answer (score 0):

My answer is to supplement Kiran's and to note that you'll get exactly the same problem as described in the question if you employ an async mergeMap.

when you use `groupBy`, as Kiren explains, it internally creates a `Subject` that immediately subscribes to the source. The following works...

```
source.pipe(
  groupBy(item => item.id),
  mergeMap(byId => {
    return byId.pipe(map(x=>service.put(x)));
  }),
```

... because (from what I can gather) the subscriptions are synchronous - mergeMap subscribes to each new grouping immediately (assuming no concurrency limits) and so it catches the data.

If you want to do something asynchronously, per grouping, you might try...

```
source.pipe(
  groupBy(item => item.id),
  mergeMap(async byId => {
    let service = await this.getSomething(byId.key); 
    return byId.pipe(map(x=>service.put(x)));
  }),
  mergeAll()
```

... at which point the subscription to the grouping Observable is deferred until `mergeAll` and it will *miss* the initial data.

The solution is exactly as Kiran says: you must use a buffering subject so that the values can be replayed when the group is finally subscribed too: 
`groupBy(item => item.id, null, null,()=>new ReplaySubject())` will work perfectly fine.

My personal solution, born of *not wanting any buffering after that initial subscription*, was to make a custom `BufferSubject` that buffers only until that first subscription and then simply passes though `next` to the base Subject.

```
/** buffers items until the first subscription, then replays them and stops buffering */
export class BufferSubject<T> extends Subject<T>{
  private _events: T[] = [];

  constructor(private scheduler?: SchedulerLike) {
    super();
  }

  next(value: T) {
    this._events.push(value);    
    super.next(value);
  }

  _subscribe(subscriber: Subscriber<T>): Subscription {
    const _events =  this._events;

    //stop buffering
    this.next = super.next;
    this._events = null;    

    const scheduler = this.scheduler;
    const len = _events.length;
    let subscription: Subscription;

    if (this.closed) {
      throw new ObjectUnsubscribedError();
    } else if (this.isStopped || this.hasError) {
      subscription = Subscription.EMPTY;
    } else {
      this.observers.push(subscriber);
      subscription = new SubjectSubscription(this, subscriber);
    }

    if (scheduler) {
      subscriber.add(subscriber = new ObserveOnSubscriber<T>(subscriber, scheduler));
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < len && !subscriber.closed; i++) {
      subscriber.next(_events[i]);
    }

    if (this.hasError) {
      subscriber.error(this.thrownError);
    } else if (this.isStopped) {
      subscriber.complete();
    }

    return subscription;
  }
}

/** from rxjs internals */
export class SubjectSubscription<T> extends Subscription {
  closed: boolean = false;

  constructor(public subject: Subject<T>, public subscriber: Observer<T>) {
    super();
  }

  unsubscribe() {
    if (this.closed) {
      return;
    }

    this.closed = true;

    const subject = this.subject;
    const observers = subject.observers;

    this.subject = null;

    if (!observers || observers.length === 0 || subject.isStopped || subject.closed) {
      return;
    }

    const subscriberIndex = observers.indexOf(this.subscriber);

    if (subscriberIndex !== -1) {
      observers.splice(subscriberIndex, 1);
    }
  }
}
```

and used instead of the replay:

```
groupBy(item => item.id, null, null,()=>new BufferSubject())
```